# Kong: Attempt to index field 'host' (a nil value)

Tags: nginx, kong, openresty

[Kong] Encounter error: Attempt to index field 'host' (a nil value)

When I use kong with high load, I encounter this issue and the stacktrace is:

```
2019/10/16 07:12:28 [error] 253#0: *109865 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/dns/balancer/base.lua:211: attempt to index field 'host' (a nil value)                                          
stack traceback:                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
coroutine 0:                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/dns/balancer/base.lua: in function 'getPeer'                                                                                                                                                
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/resty/dns/balancer/ring.lua:319: in function 'getPeer'                                                                                                                                            
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/runloop/balancer.lua:834: in function 'execute'                                                                                                                                              
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/runloop/handler.lua:753: in function 'balancer_execute'                                                                                                                                      
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/runloop/handler.lua:1260: in function 'after'                                                                                                                                                
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:745: in function 'access'                                                                                                                                                           
        access_by_lua(nginx-kong.conf:89):2: in main chunk
```